# What is happening when you have a function as a parameter?

Tags: lua

I'm still ramping up in lua, and I am not quite familiar with this syntax. What is happening when you pass in a function as a parameter like below?

```
Comm.setRouting(function(url)
        for i = 1,4 do
            local portIndex = "Path"..i
            if url:match(portConfig[portIndex]) ~= nil then
                return Comm.slots()[1], Comm.groups()[i]
            end
        end
    end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're passing an argument to `setRouting` that is an "anonymous function"

Functions are first-class values in Lua and can be stored in local variables, global variables and table fields. Here the function is being passed anonymously on the call stack to the `setRouting` function.

`setRouting` would be called a "higher-order function" because it accepts a function as its input.

The following page has some more information about functions in Lua:

https://www.lua.org/pil/6.html

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, but it might help you if you [wrote your own](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) function that calls another function:

```lua
function CallAFunction(func_to_call)
   func_to_call()
end
```

You could pass a named function (an anonymous function assigned to a variable) or an anonymous function written on the fly.

```lua
function SayHello()
   print("Hello!")
end
--[[
^This is equivalent to:
SayHello = function()
   print("Hello!")
end
]]--

CallAFunction(SayHello)
CallAFunction(function()
                  print("Goodbye!")
              end)
```

output:

```
Hello!
Goodbye!
```

and this can be done with parameters

```lua
function CallAFunction(func)
   func("Bonjour")
end

CallAFunction(function(parameter)
                  print(parameter)
              end)
```

Here, `func` is the anonymous function, which accepts 1 parameter `parameter`.
When you call `func("Bonjour")` you are passing Bonjour as `parameter`, like a normal function call.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are happening in this example:

1. You're passing a function as a parameter.  The callee (e.g. `setRouting()`) can invoke that function.  This is often referred to as a [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).
2. You're defining the function itself, on-the-fly.  This is an example of an "anonymous function", or a [lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).